# Multi-region NoSQL database solutions

Tags: architecture, nosql

I'm wanting to write a program that handles financial data with multi region support. The main reason I want multi region support is so users get very low latency access to updating/reading data.

The problem I have is what if a user for example has a balance of $10 in their account and they attempt to withdraw that $10 at the exact same time on two different regions. The requests can both go through as the two database nodes haven't fully synced with each other yet.  I'm not sure if there is a name for this issue.

I would much rather use a NoSQL database than a SQL database. If anyone has any solutions or even any ideas that would be much appreciated.

I was originally looking into MongoDB but you cannot write to a secondary node in a replica set.

I have looked into CassandraDB because Discord uses it to support thousands of users over multiple regions with high-throughput. I'm not sure if this will fix my issue.

I have also thought about only allowing a user a session token or login on one region at a time, but this will mean I will have to check the location of the user semi-often. (My users may be changing regions quite often, even mid-session). Maybe this is the best solution, but I'm not sure.